# Python Script (Reddit bot) resets variables on http error/timeout

Tags: python, bots, reddit, reconnect

To be upfront...I'm still very new to Python.  I have a reddit bot that reads a single designated post in a subreddit I moderate.  Based on the syntax of responses, it replies and stores variables (e.g. commenter name, an incremental number, already_seen).

If reddit times out or has a 500/504 error my bot resets its variables.  The next time it successfully loads the post, it treats all user comments as new and responds to them again.

Additionally, I have tested this by temporarily disconnecting my internet.  As soon as it reconnects the bot does the same thing.

Is there a way I can make the bot wait and still remember that it has seen and responded to pre-existing posts?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, thank you.

For all my searching and browsing, this is as much as I have come up with (again, I'm new to this):

```
except(IOError):
    time.sleep(30)
    pass
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of code that we can run and shows the problem? Right now, the problem could be literally anything since we don't know what the code looks like.

Comment: @user3448867 So you are trying to make it remember if it has seen a users post? If so can the user can post multiple times? If they can  I would a dict as such, `dictionary.setdefault(user, []).append(what_they_said)`and then iterate through the dictionary and check if the post/user is already there. I'll answer with some example code since I'm not sure what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to wrap internet access code with a try-catch block. if the page fetch fails, you skip the current loop and continue with the next iteration

psedo code:

```
while True:
  content = None
  try:
    content = fetch_content # might have error
  except:
    continue
  # do reply logic

  sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get it to remember the posts then you could add this to your code somewhere once it replies/sees the users post

```
posts = dict()
# some code reading or replying to the comments
posts.setdefault(user, []).append(post) # get posts[user] if it exists, if not create it with a list value, then append the post.
# some of your other code to check if it's in the dictionary
```

Like maybe

```
for post in posts:
    ...
```